# Can't Get Access Token

Tags: google-oauth

I'm using Google Analytics API in my project. I make some changes on project and moved Google Analytics connection from library to CURL requests with Faraday.

I get CODE params from URL and it all went great. But when I try to get "tokens" it gives me this strange error.

```
conn = Faraday.new(url: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com')

response = conn.post '/token', {
code: @google_analytics_connection.code,
client_id: 'client_id',
client_secret: 'client_secret',
redirect_uri: 'return_uri',
grant_type: 'authorization_code'
}, {
'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
```

I checked over and over again all my credentials. These variables are true. However I got this error;

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "\nYou can&#39;t sign in to this app because it doesn&#39;t comply with Google&#39;s OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.\n\nYou can let the app developer know that this app doesn&#39;t comply with one or more Google validation rules.\n  "
}
```

When I try to authorize for the first time Google didn't show any warning. Also I checked my developer console for any warning etc, there is no issue there too.

Request made to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token as explained in the documentation.

What do I missing? I checked my redirect_uri, client_id and client_secret over and over again. They all seems okay.

What is missing?

Comment: please edit your code and include [example]  make sure your redirect uri is https

Comment: I updated code @Linda Lawton - DalmTo